# Regarding storage permission for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Two questions about storage permission for Chrome extensions.

1. I have a published extension. If I add a storage permission to manifest.json, will the extension be disabled for current users (i.e., Chrome asks if the user want to allow the new permissions), or will it keep running without asking them?
2. From what version of Chrome is chrome.storage available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try it or [read the documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings.html#nowarning):

   > The following permissions don't result in a warning: (...)
   >
   > - "storage"
2. [Version 20](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html#20).

Comment: It wasn't that we didn't read it, just that we didn't fint it. But thanks for answering! Much appreciated.

Comment: Today, this permission still don't result in a warning